# How to get All companies data from tally xml api?

Tags: xml, integration, tally

I am trying to export data from tally through API. Lets say tally is configured with more than one companies, I can able to get the svcurrent company purchase vouchers only using following payload.

```
<ENVELOPE>  
 <HEADER>  
   <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>  
 </HEADER>  
 <BODY>  
   <EXPORTDATA>  
     <REQUESTDESC>  
       <!-- Specify the Report Name here -->  
       <REPORTNAME>PurchaseVouchers</REPORTNAME>
       <STATICVARIABLES>
            <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
           <!--Specify the Period here-->
            <SVFROMDATE>20181001</SVFROMDATE>
            <SVTODATE>20181001</SVTODATE>
       </STATICVARIABLES>
     </REQUESTDESC>  
   </EXPORTDATA>  
 </BODY>  
</ENVELOPE>
```

How to get select company and get purchase vouchers through API?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some tags and haven't mentioned what you want to fetch. Example -

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
    <ID>FindParticularVoucher</ID>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <DESC>
      <STATICVARIABLES>
        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>COMPANY NAME</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
        <VCHTYPE>PurchaseVouchers</VCHTYPE>
        <SVFROMDATE TYPE="DATE">01-05-2019</SVFROMDATE>
        <SVTODATE TYPE="DATE">31-05-2019</SVTODATE>
      </STATICVARIABLES>
      <TDL>
        <TDLMESSAGE>
          <COLLECTION NAME="FindParticularVoucher" ISINITIALIZE="YES">
            <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>
            <FETCH>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.*</FETCH>
            <FETCH>ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.*</FETCH>
            <FILTER>GetInvoiceVoucher</FILTER>
          </COLLECTION>
          <VARIABLE NAME="VCHTYPE">
            <TYPE>String</TYPE>
          </VARIABLE>
          <SYSTEM TYPE="FORMULAE" NAME="GetInvoiceVoucher">$VoucherTypeName = $$String:##VCHTYPE</SYSTEM>
        </TDLMESSAGE>
      </TDL>
    </DESC>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

For purchase vouchers, between the tag **VCHTYPE** and its closing tag - just insert whatever your purchase voucher is named as. For example in my company I have two different type of purchase voucher and one of them is named **Purchase Interstate**. So thats what I would insert between those tags.

Now if you want to get all the purchase voucher types, you can replace the **VCHTYPE** tag as follows -

```
<VCHTYPE1>Purchase Interstate</VCHTYPE1>
<VCHTYPE2>Purchase State</VCHTYPE2>
```

And at the end of the XML, your formula (in the **SYSTEM** tag) would change to -

```
<SYSTEM TYPE="FORMULAE" NAME="GetInvoiceVoucher">$VoucherTypeName = $$String:##VCHTYPE1 or $VoucherTypeName = $$String:##VCHTYPE2</SYSTEM>
```

Note - make sure to change the company name in this XML code. Just remember you'll get back an XML response and you'll need to deserialize it. That is how tally works.